Why is $l^p \subset l^q$ but $L^q ([0,1]) \subset L^p([0,1])$
Let $L^p([0,1])$ be the completion of $C ([0,1])$. For $1\leq p < q<\infty$, why $l^p \subset l^q$ but $L^q\subset L^p$ instead of $L^p \subset L^q$?
Update: According to one of the answers, the reason is $l^p$ functions don't have singularities, while the behavior of a function's growth around singularities is the main determinant on whether a function is in $L^p[0,1]$ or not. May I understand it as:
A function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ in $l^p$ (as a vector) has $|f|<1$ eventually, so we can use prove $l^p \subset l^q$ if $p<q$ by eg. rescaling $f$ to satisfy $||f||_p=1$. But a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ in $L^p$ could have $f$ diverge to infinity around singularities, so we cannot rescale and get a similar proof for $L^p$.

A big difference between $L^p$ and $\ell^p$ is that there are no "singularities" (i.e., when a function spikes to $\infty$ in a finite-measured region) in $\ell^p$ functions, since the measure is on a discrete set. The behavior of a function's growth around singularities is the main determinant on whether a function is in $L^p[0,1]$ or not, so this is a significant qualitative difference between how we tell a function is in $L^p$ vs $\ell^p$.

@HIH: $\ell_q(\mathbb{N})\subset\ell_p(\mathbb{N})$ for all $0<p<q$ since $\inf{\mu(E): \mu(E)>0}=1>0$  where $\mu$ is the counting measure, whilst $L_p([0,1])\subset L_q(0,1])$ for all $0<p<q$ since $\sup{m(E): m(E)<\infty}=1<\infty$ where $m$ is Lebeusge measure. The difference is in that one of the underlying measures is purely atomic and infinite (counting measure) and the other is finite and continuous (Lebesgue measure).

What do you mean by why? I'll simply list two differences.
$l^{p}(\mathbb{N})$ is like $L^{p}(\mathbb{R},\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure concentrated on $\mathbb{N}.$
The second difference is that in $L^{p}([0,1])$ the constant $1$ belongs to every $L^{r}([0,1])$ for every $r \geq 1,$ this allows you to use the Holder inequality to prove the inclusion $L^{2}([0,1]) \subset L^{1}([0,1])$ . On the other hand, the function $1$ does not belong to any of the $l^{p}(\mathbb{N})!$ Additionaly, the inclusion $l^{1} \subset l^{2}$ holds because the measure that I previously called $\mu$ is $\sigma-$finite, and concentrated on a countable set of points, and ,like pointed out in the comments, the measure of all the points is equal to a non zero constant. This allows you to exploit a property about the coefficients of convergent series together with the comparison test of the series!
I hope this answers to your question, I tried to stay as intuitive as possible.

Your answer is rather vague and in fact not quite correct. Consider $\mathbb{N}$ equipped with the power set $\sigma$-algebra. Define $\mu$ as the measure such that $\mu({n})=\frac1n$. This measure is $\sigma$-finite, concentrated in a countable set of points (even $\mathbf{1}\not\in L_1(\mu)$) and yet, $L_1(\mu)\not\subset L_2(\mu)$ because $\inf{\mu(E): \mu(E)>0}=0$. Notice also that $L_1(\mu)\not\supset L_2(\mu)$ since $\sup{\mu(E): \mu(E)<\infty}=\infty$.

Thanks for pointing it out, now it should be correct. Because if all points have the same measure being in $l^{1}$ means having an absolutely convergent series,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\vert a_{k} \vert.
$$
This implies being square integrable because the coefficients are all limited by a common constant $K,$ and thus
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} a_{k}^{2} \leq K \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \vert a_{k} \vert < +\infty
$$

Being very hand-wavey: because things fail to be in $\ell^p$ because they don't go to $0$ quickly enough at $\infty$, while things fail to be in $L^p([0,1)])$ because they go to $\infty$ too quickly at some finite point.

If a sequence $(a_k)_{k\ge1} \,$ has finite  $\,l^p$-norm, then the sequence
$\vert a_k \vert ^p$ converges to zero. If you consider $q>p$ then intuitively the sequence $\vert a_k \vert ^q$ will converge to $0$ faster than $\vert a_k \vert ^p$, because for some $N \ge 1$ it holds $\forall n\ge N : \vert a_n \vert \le 1$. Hence $a_k$ is also in $l^q$, since we can bound $\vert a \vert _{l^q}$ with $\vert a\vert _{l^p}$:
$$ \vert a \vert _{l^q}^q = \sum_{k\ge 1} \vert a_k \vert ^q   \le \sum_{N >k\ge 1} \vert a_k \vert ^q + \sum_{k\ge N} \vert a_k \vert ^p \le \sum_{N >k\ge 1} \vert a_k \vert ^q + \vert a \vert ^p_{l^p}< \infty$$
We conclude $l^p \subset l^q$.
On the other hand, for a function $f$ in $L^p([0,1])$ you don't have any similar condition, (f may even diverge in $[0, 1]$), so $\vert f\vert _{L^q}$ cannot be bounded by $\vert f \vert _{L^p}$.
